Getting login link from Next api route using next-auth rest api (Next app router)?
When someone subscribe to my saas using an email. I want to send him a login link to his email.  For that I am using next-auth. It has rest api. It seems like not working.
`export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const { email } = await request.json();
  // Fetch CSRF token
  const csrfRes = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}/api/auth/csrf`);
  const csrfData = await csrfRes.json();
  const { csrfToken } = csrfData;

  // Send magic link
  const signInRes = await fetch(
    `${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}/api/auth/signin/email`,
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
      body: new URLSearchParams({
        email,
        csrfToken,
        callbackUrl: `${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}`,
        json: "true",
      }),
    },
  );

  const data = await signInRes.json();

  ....`your text`

}`

**Instead of the login link I am getting this:**

`{ url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin?csrf=true' }`


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
